# Why is String.charCodeAt(str) not working here?

Tags: javascript

Str is a number. Therefore String.charCodeAt() should work just fine. Were is my code going wrong?

```
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  var tempNums = "";
  for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if(str.charCodeAt(i) <= 78 && str.charCodeAt(i) > 64) {
        var tempLocalNum = str.charCodeAt(i) + 13;
        tempNums += tempLocalNum;
      }
      else if(str.charCodeAt(i) > 78 && str.charCodeAt(i) < 91) {
        var tempLocalNumMin = str.charCodeAt(i) - 13;
        tempNums += tempLocalNumMin;
      }
      else {
        tempNums += str.charCodeAt(i);
      }
  }  
  var newStr = String.fromCharCode(tempNums);
  return newStr;
}
```

rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: FREE CODE CAMP is the expected output

Comment: your "tempNums" ends up being `7082696932677968693267917780` - does that help you realise what you did wrong?

Comment: yes thank you kind sir!

Comment: your cutoff logic is wrong too ... < 78 in the first if, and >= 78 in the second, otherwise you get `FREE CODE C[MP` ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what this is supposed to acheive, but I made some changes where indicated. Does it help:

```
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  var tempNums = "";
  for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if(str.charCodeAt(i) <= 78 && str.charCodeAt(i) > 64) {
        var tempLocalNum = str.charCodeAt(i) + 13;
        tempNums += String.fromCharCode(tempLocalNum);//here
      }
      else if(str.charCodeAt(i) > 78 && str.charCodeAt(i) < 91) {
        var tempLocalNumMin = str.charCodeAt(i) - 13;
        tempNums += String.fromCharCode(tempLocalNumMin);//here
      }
      else {
        tempNums += String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i));//here
      }
  }  
  //var newStr = String.fromCharCode(tempNums);//here
  return tempNums;//newStr;//and here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

But `var tempNums = "";` will return `7082696932677968693267917780` according to the operation you are performing & doing  `String.fromCharCode(tempNums)`; will not return any result.

Also `var tempNums = 0;` will produce 952 and doing `String.fromcharCode(tempNums)` is producing θ (Theta)

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/96qehvj5/) is what I tried in jsfiddle